# How to access a local using a variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following code.

mymodule

```
variable "senses" {
  type = string
}


locals {
  sounds = {
    "cat" = "meow"
    "dog" = ["bark", "woof"]
  }
}

output "noise" {
  value = local[var.senses]["cat"]
}
```

call mymodule

```
module "mymodule" {
  source = "../../../modules/mymodule"
  senses = "sound"
}
```

returns error:

```
Error: Invalid reference

  on ../../../modules/mymodule/outputs.tf line 62, in output "noise":
  62:   value = local[var.senses]["cat"]

The "local" object cannot be accessed directly. Instead, access one of its
attributes.
```

my code can't seem to handle

```
value = local[var.senses]["cat"]
```

Any suggestions on how i can get this to work?

Comment: What exactly is `var.senses`?

Comment: hi @Marcin. var.senses is the string "sound"

Comment: I see. No, you can't do this. such syntax is not supported in TF. It must be `local.sound["cat"]`.

Comment: ah bummer, i could really use this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to use a variable to switch which `local` you're reading.  I.e. `local[var.senses]` is the root of the issue.

If you refactor slightly and put your values inside a single, known, value--such as `local.senses` it should then let you do a key lookup within that value.

So, if you modify your `locals` to place your values in a `senses` key:

```
locals {
  senses = {
    "sounds" = {
      "cat" = "meow"
      "dog" = ["bark", "woof"]
    }
  }
}
```

and update your lookup to use that field:

```
value = local.senses[var.senses]["cat"]
```

Then I believe it will work, since your are doing a key lookup against a specific `local` rather than trying to dynamically select the `local`.